# Remote drive size reports more space than the physical disk drive actually possesses. Why?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Two logical drives (S and Z) are mapped by a Windows 7 Pro (64-Bit) PC.  Each of the logical drives (both pointing to the same Windows 2008 Server) say that the space available is 555 GB out of 445 GB, which is clearly impossible.  I've attached a screenshot of the Windows 7 Explorer program.  Can anyone tell me what is causing this and how to correct it?

Windows 7 Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer screen capture]

Comment: is this causing a problem?  are you in control of the servers?

Comment: Do you have any adtional info of those drives? Seeing that screen cap I'd assume that it's a conflict between what you are allowed to "see" versus the real free space of that drive, or something along those lines

Comment: There are no size allocation limits configured (on the server) for the drives.  If someone connects to that shared drive name then the entire space on the drive should be available.  It is this way on the other remote drives on other Windows 2008 server shares, as shown in the captured picture.